# vtiger can't set the outgoing server

Tags: php, vtiger

I want to set the outgoing server.

I went to setting then cRM settings then outgoing server. and I entered my information as bellow

[image]

I keep getting the mentioned error message. I tried a lot and checked all the posted discussion on the vtiger forum but nothing help and I can see that all the people have a problem with this configuration

**Noice: I installed vtiger on my localhost and I didn't change anything in any php file**

Comment: As per my knowledge you can't setup Outgoing Server in localhost. It will not work for Vtiger CRM

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while since this question was asked but I've been through the mill on this one - generally **vTiger 6** e-mail configuration has less than helpful error messages! I figured it would be good to put some of what i've learned on here!

Several things to check for (under linux as that's what i'm using):

- Make sure your firewall is not blocking outbound data
- ensure that the server at the remote side works with SMTP

This is specific to to those Linuxes that use SELinux:

as root (or sudo'd as root)

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

This allows the web server to work with e-mail. Without that setting I was seeing things where I tested stuff in php from the command line working but the exact same test from the web server, it failed.

If you're comfortable with php, use the debug techniques as outlined in [this document](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/DebugTechniques):

> Turn on log4php.debug library usage, in file config.performance.php
>
> > > 'LOG4PHP_DEBUG' => true,

> Set the log level, in file log4php.properties
>
> > > log4php.rootLogger = DEBUG, A1

> **Note: Make sure logs/ folder has write access to apache server process owner.**

That should give enough on what its doing (or not as the case usually is!).